# Optimal way to declare an adapter for a RecyclerView

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView (`id = myList`) running but I have a question about what is the correct and optimal way to declare an RecyclerView:

```
val myRecycler = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.myList)
myRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
myRecycler.adapter = CustomAdapter(items)
```

Or in this way:

```
myList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
myList.adapter = CustomAdapter(items)
```

Both cases work correctly for me, in the second case it is not necessary to use `findViewById`. Which is better?

Comment: Using `myList` synthetic property seems more idiomatic since it removes redundant explicit findViewById call and one variable declaration.
Synthetic declarations also generate code that caches a reference to a view so findViewById called one time.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#view-binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin helps a developer to write concise code without affecting its readability. So the developer do not have to worry about writing boilerplate code anymore.

By adding this :

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

in the build gradle for app, kotlin can automatically detect the view id for you so that you do not have to write "findViewById" anymore.

So a more kotlin way to write the above piece of code is :

```
myList.apply {
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    adapter = CustomAdapter(items)
}
```

(Note : "kotlin-android-extensions" does much more than just finding the view id automatically for you, just refer [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) for all its features.)

Comment: I had added extensions for the issue of sending an ArrayList to another activity (Parcelable). Thanks for the info. I'm clear now..

Answer (score 1):

Can not tell for sure but I suppose these are equal or almost equal in device resource consumption. As you know, nowdays devices are much more powerful in comparison to 4-5years old devices so many developers prefer easier and shorter code even it is a bit less efficient.
For me this code is the best:

```
myList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
myList.adapter = CustomAdapter(items)
```